# Error on c# code

Tags: c#

Hello everyone I have a problem in c# code.I am creating own DAL here is my code when i am create this function i have an error

****object does not contain a definition for rows no extension method accepting first argument of type could be found are you missing using directive an assembly reference?)****

```
public static void AddRemoveCmbItem(string Add_Remove, ref System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmb, Int16 iRow, string Add_Item)
        {
            if ((Add_Remove == "Add"))
            {
                if (!(Add_Item == null))
                {
                    DataRow NewRow = cmb.DataSource.NewRow();
                    // Warning!!! Optional parameters not supported
                    NewRow[cmb.DisplayMember] = ("       " + Add_Item);
                    NewRow[cmb.ValueMember] = iRow;
                    cmb.DataSource.Rows.InsertAt(NewRow, iRow);
                }
            }
            else if ((iRow <= cmb.DataSource.rows.count))
            {

                cmb.DataSource.Rows.RemoveAt(iRow);
            }
```

Comment: `DataSource` is of type `Object`. You need to cast it to your expected type. I assume your datasource is `DataTable`; so just cast it to `DataTable` and use.

Comment: Please copy and paste the *exact* error message rather than retyping it, losing capitalization and other information. Next, look at the type of `ComboBox.DataSource` - where would you expect the `Rows` property to come from? Next, note that C# is case-sensitive - `rows` isn't the same as `rows`, and `Count` isn't the same as `count`. Next, read up about `ref` - there's no indication that you actually want or need it here.

Answer (score 0):

'object' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is I have found actual error